# Dividing Two Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've seen questions on this sort of thing before, but they all involved power series, whereas my question is slightly more general.

I want to divide two absolutely convergent series with the following form:

$$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n^2-1)g(q;n)}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g(q;n)}$$

I want to figure out a way to condense this down to one series. If it helps, the functional forms for $g$ are make these alternating series (they still converge absolutely), so it's possible to rewrite $g(q;n)$ as $(-1)^{n-1}g(q;n)$

Comment: What is g(q; n)?

Comment: The dependency on $q$ is immaterial. Consider writing $g_n$ for clarity. And you can immediately pull $-1$ out of the ratio.

Comment: I wanted to clarify that there's another variable upon which $g$ depends. The specific identity $g$ is irrelevant: it only matters that it's the same function and depends on both n and another variable. And why can we pull the -1 out of the ratio?

Comment: Never mind, I just realized that I can use the distributive property to simplify out the series in the denominator and get the $n^2$ series divided by the denominator series minus 1 in the end.